# R stacked percentage bar plot with percentage of binary factor and labels

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph, graphics

I want to produce a graphic that looks something like this (with percentage and legend) by R:

[image]

My original data is:

```
         AIRBUS BOEING EMBRAER
  2002     18     21      30
  2003     20     23      31
  2004     23     26      29
  2005     22     25      26
  2006     22     25      25
  2007     22     27      17
  2008     21     21      16
  2009     17     19      22
  2010     14     22      24
  2011     17     27      22
  2012     16     22      19
  2013     11     24      19
```

[image]

There are similar questions on SO already, but I seem to lack the sufficient amount of intelligence (or understanding of R) to extrapolate from them to a solution to my particular problem.

Comment: Percentage of what? Do the numbers represent percentage or do you need to calculate the percentage of total each year?

Comment: The numbers are already represent percentage. I need them to be seen on top of the bar, similar to the plot above. Also, I don't know how to add a title for the plot. I have tried:   ggtitle("Departure delays by company and Year") but it's not working. also, I would like to see all the years on axle x and not only 2005 and 2010. 
Thank you very much!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `gather` or `melt` your data into long format. Then it's easy.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(
  text = "
  YEAR AIRBUS BOEING EMBRAER
  2002     18     21      30
  2003     20     23      31
  2004     23     26      29
  2005     22     25      26
  2006     22     25      25
  2007     22     27      17
  2008     21     21      16
  2009     17     19      22
  2010     14     22      24
  2011     17     27      22
  2012     16     22      19
  2013     11     24      19",
  header = TRUE
)


df_long <- df %>% 
  gather(company, percentage, AIRBUS:EMBRAER)

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = YEAR, y = percentage, fill = company)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  ggtitle("Departure delays by company and Year") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2002:2013)
```

[image]

Comment: First, Thank you very much! The numbers are already represent percentage. I need them to be seen on top of the bar, similar to the plot above. Also, I don't know how to add a title for the plot. I have tried: ggtitle("Departure delays by company and Year") but it's not working. also, I would like to see all the years on axle x and not only 2005 and 2010. Thank you :)

Comment: Did you add (`+`) the `ggtitle(...)`? The basics of ggplot are that you add features together. For x axis ticks of course you just use the standard `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2002:2013)`